# Why is my display text blurry

Tags: windows-7, display, graphics-card, hdmi

I bought a new computer recently and when I connect it into my older Samsung display with a HDMI cable the text seems to be blurry. However if I connect my older laptop computer into this same Samsung display with a VGA-cable, then there is no problem.

For example, when I look at this [site](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm) (on the left and right of the site) with my new computer connected to the older Samsung display with a HDMI-cable, the black and white background seems to be flashing. If I look the same page with my older laptop connected with VGA, the website is not flashing.

What might be causing this issue? Is it with the properties of my display card or is the display itself too old? The display is by the way < 6 years old. When I look at the text I'm writing right now it seems blurry. I added a screen capture, but I don't know if you can see the problem:

[image]

For example if you look at the image on the left you can see (or at least I can on my new computer) that the text shadowed in the background has this strange "white shadow" in it.

How to fix this? =) Thank you for any help! Please let me know if you need more info. My OS is Win 7 HomeBasic.

Comment: As the display is perhaps up to five years old, there might be dust in the HDMI port. You could try blowing into it and reinserting the HDMI plug a few times to see if it improves. If not, I suggest trying another HDMI cable just to see if that improves the image.

Comment: +1 Thank you @AndrewMorton, will try it right away! :) Blowing into HDMI-port or trying another HDMI-cable did not work :/

Comment: Do you have any other devices which you could plug into the Samsung display via HDMI so that you can narrow down which part is misbehaving?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I can try my laptop or PS3 with HDMI, let me try my laptop with HDMI :) Update: laptop does the same thing if connected with HDMI! So is the problem in the display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself. The problem is in the display. I tried another display and the problem went away. Thank you @AndrewMorton for your help!

Comment: You're welcome :) I was also going to suggest making sure that there are no other connections plugged into the display at the same time as the HDMI - it shouldn't make a difference, but there is a *chance* of something interfering with the signal.

Comment: Roger that, actually there are other wires connected. I can try that option as well :) thank you, excellent job ;)

Comment: Disconnecting other wires did not help. Thank you anyway! I need to remember that =)